# facebook sdk ios expiration date

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios

I'm trying to record token and expiration date of facebook for not authorize user every time. But tonight I got this error an error like: `{"error":{"type":"OAuthException"`.
First let me explain how and when I record expiration date and token:

In `DidLogin`:

```
-(void)fbDidLogin{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:facebook.accessToken            forKey:@"fb_access_token"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"fb_expiration_date"];
```

And in login:

```
facebook.accessToken    = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"fb_access_token"];
facebook.expirationDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fb_expiration_date"];

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSLog(@"session not valid authorize again"); 
    [facebook authorize:_permissions delegate:self];
}   
else
{
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFB_login)])[delegate didFB_login];
    self.loggedin=TRUE;
}
```

After some `NSLog` I understood the problem:

My expiration date is

```
exp date:4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

So for ensure I'm not falling in mistake I modified `facebook.m`:

```
//FBLoginDialogDelegate

/**
* Set the authToken and expirationDate after login succeed
*/
- (void)fbDialogLogin:(NSString *)token expirationDate:(NSDate *)expirationDate {
self.accessToken = token;
self.expirationDate = expirationDate;
NSLog(@"self.expirationDate:%@",self.expirationDate);
if ([self.sessionDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(fbDidLogin)]) {
[_sessionDelegate fbDidLogin];
}

}
```

then forced a new authorize call but the result is still:

```
self.expirationDate:4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

Now the question is: is there a bug in Facebook OAuth? How can I be sure that problem is not in my date saving code?

Answer (score 2):

FB is deprecating the use of "offline_access" for long lived sessions. Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/ for more information.

And here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#extend_token if you're developing in iOS.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Damn after some debug i found that
handleOpenURL
query:access_token=accesstokenstring&expires_in=0

Why OAuth answer me expires_in 0 ? offcourse the date is 4001 cause

```
// We have an access token, so parse the expiration date.
NSString *expTime = [params valueForKey:@"expires_in"];
NSLog(@"expTime:%@",expTime);
NSDate *expirationDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
if (expTime != nil) {
int expVal = [expTime intValue];
if (expVal != 0) {
  expirationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:expVal];
```

expVal is 0 so expiration date is distantFuture.
But token was expiried and i got oauth expection when i try to query with that token..
So? Anyone has idea?

Solved.. If anyone want to know why this happen this is the answer: The expires_in was 0 due to offline_access permission.. Burt token was expiried server side due to facebook password change. To fix this just add in

```
  - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

NSLog(@"didFailWithError : %@",[error description]);

NSDictionary* userinfo=[error userInfo];
// NSLog(@"userinfo:%@",userinfo);
NSString *type=[[userinfo valueForKey:@"error"]valueForKey:@"type"];
// NSLog(@"type:%@",type);
if([type isEqualToString:@"OAuthException"]){
    NSLog(@"Exception from oauth let's take new token");
[facebook authorize:_permissions delegate:self];

}
```

Comment: Solved.. If anyone want to know why this happen this is the answer: